# i have problem with one to one extends user model

Tags: django

hi friends i want extends user model with fields from other table (structure) as foreignkey .. i will show you my models and the error after creation of super user

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from immob.models import structure
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    User = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    structure_id = models.ForeignKey(structure, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_utilisateur(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
        Profile.objects.create(User=instance)


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_utilisateur(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

Error message:

```
[p-amc-dgps-er@192-168-150-254 Invest_App]$ python3 manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'p-amc-dgps-er'): admin
Email address: admin@admin.dz
Password: 
Password (again): 
Error: Your passwords didn't match.
Password: 
Password (again): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: ERREUR:  une instruction insert ou update sur la table �� compte_profile �� viole la contrainte de cl��
��trang��re �� compte_utilisateur_structure_id_id_df7f99e8_fk_immob_str ��
DETAIL:  La cl�� (structure_id_id)=(0) n'est pas pr��sente dans la table �� immob_structure ��.
```

Comment: if you translate error message in English then it's helping others to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `default=0` on your `structure_id` foreign key. You can't set a default to 0 if there is no `structure` row with this id. So you have to ask yourself the following:

- Is `structure_id` mandatory? If not, add `blank=True, null=True` and don't set a default value (let it be `None`).
- If it is mandatory, then you need to assign a `structure` object as default, but that also means that in your migrations, you need to make sure a `structure` object is created in your database before you can create the `Profile` table. You would need to set `default=get_default_structure` and define the `get_default_structure()` function to return the one you want (e.g. `return structure.objects.get(name='default')`).

Note 1: I would advise you to not call the foreign key field `structure_id` but `structure`, because in your python code, `profile.structure_id` doesn't give you the id but the actual `structure` instance. Look at the Django documentation for `ForeignKey`: Behind the scenes, Django stores the id (and automatically creates a `structure_id` field), but for you as a developer, Django ForeignKeys work with the actual objects you're referring to.

Note 2: Also don't call your user field `User` but `user`, since inside the namespace of `Profile` you're actually redefining the class `User` by using CamelCase. Python instance variables and class attributes should always be lowercase (snake_case). Only class names are uppercase (CamelCase).

Comment: i do changes and i got                                          
  ProgrammingError at /compte/login/
    ERREUR:  la colonne compte_profile.structure_id n'existe pas
    LINE 1: ...compte_profile"."id", "compte_profile"."User_id", "compte_pr...
    HINT:  Peut-être que vous souhaitiez référencer la colonne «
    compte_profile.structure_id_id ».
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/compte/login/

Comment: Did you makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: yes i do it and i got this when i create superuser                                                                  profile.objects.create(user=instance)
NameError: name 'profile' is not defined

Comment: Make sure it’s Profile not profile. Also in the code of your question you’re indenting the @receiver code inside class Profile but it should not be indented.

Comment: [p-amc-dgps-er@192-168-150-254 Invest_App]$ python3 manage.py makemigrations 
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'structure' to profile without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:

Comment: that goes back to the answer I give: is structure mandatory or not? Follow the instructions I gave in my answer.

Comment: i do it but when i try to create super user i got this new errordjango.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "compte_profile" violates foreign key constraint "compte_profile_structure_id_id_64aa8f25_fk_immob_structure_id"
DETAIL:  Key (structure_id_id)=(0) is not present in table "immob_structure". for more information i insert manually records in immob_structure table in database before i create superuser

Comment: You’re still using default=0? How did you specify default? Update your question to show what you’re doing.